# What is the phrase for a publication that publishes articles with differing opinions

Tags: phrases, publishing

One day it may post an article listing 10 reasons why living in Lapland is the worst, and then another day it may list 10 reasons why living in Lapland is the best.

Compare this to newspapers in the UK where each have their own political bias from which they never shift in any of their articles.

I believe it is called something along the lines of "editorial..." in regards to the editor who agrees to publish the article.

Comment: Editorial suicide? :P It's not necessarily indicative of posting *conflicting* articles, but ***scandal sheet*** might be appropriate: "a newspaper or magazine giving prominence to scandalous stories or gossip." It could be considered scandalous to post articles that contradict each other.

Comment: Are you just looking for _impartiality_?

Answer (score 1):

I think that not **all** uk newspapers have the bias you refer to, but a paper without that bias could be called "independent" (not to be confused with the actual newspaper The Independent).

What you're talking about, in your example at least, isn't anything to do with political bias, just differing opinions:  you could say that it represents "**diverse opinions**" or "**a wide range of viewpoints**".

Answer (score 0):

I think it is **Editorial Policy**

> [...] therefore the newspaper's editor was free to decide **editorial policy**, including its political allegiance.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daily_Mail